# How to call forms['myform'].submit with input with name 'submit' exists

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form which contains input element

```
<form name='myform'>
    <input name='submit'>
</form>
```

How do I call `forms['myform'].submit()`? `forms['myform'].submit` refers to input element an not the function.

Comment: why do you want the name of the input as submit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steal the submit method from another form

```
document.createElement('form').submit.apply(document.forms.myform);
```

This **will not work in IE6**. Changing the name of the submit button is the safer, more reliable, simpler option.